# Problems Implementing Multithreaded mergeSort in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multithreading, sorting, mergesort

I am new to coding for parallel processing and am attempting to implement a multithreaded Merge Sort algorithm. I am unclear on the proper usage of threads and how exactly it works, but I attempted to implement it anyway and this is where I landed. (tells me that slice is not a function)

```js
function pMergeSort(input, done) {
 const spawn = require('threads').spawn;


 if (input.length< 2)
  return input;
 function partition(arr) { 
 let middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
 let left = arr.sclice(0, middle);
 let right = arr.slice(middle + 1, arr.length);
 }
  let left,right=partition(input);
 let task = spawn(pMergeSort).send(left).on('done', function (arr) {
  if (result === undefined) {
   for (let i = 0; i< n.length; i++) {
    result[i] = n[i];
   }
  }else {
   merge(result, n);
   left.kill();
  }
 });
 pMergeSort(right, function (n) {
  if (result === undefined) {
   for (let i = 0; i< n.length; i++) {
    result[i] = n[i];
   }
  }else {
   merge(result, n);
   right.kill();
  }
 });

}

/*
function mergeSort (arr) {
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        // return once we hit an array with a single item
        return arr
    }

    const middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2) // get the middle item of the array rounded down
    const left = arr.slice(0, middle) // items on the left side
    const right = arr.slice(middle) // items on the right side

    return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right))
}*/

// compare the arrays item by item and return the concatenated result
function merge(left, right) {
 let result = []
 let indexLeft = 0
 let indexRight = 0

 while (indexLeft < left.length && indexRight < right.length) {
  if (left[indexLeft] < right[indexRight]) {
   result.push(left[indexLeft])
   indexLeft++
  } else {
   result.push(right[indexRight])
   indexRight++
  }
 }
 return result.concat(left.slice(indexLeft)).concat(right.slice(indexRight))
}
function genArray(size) {
 // randomly fills arr
 var arr = Array(size);
 for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 98);
 }
 return arr
}
function testParallel(){
 var array=genArray(Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
 pMergeSort(array, function(i){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(i));
 })
}
var testArr = genArray(2);
pMergeSort(testArr, function (i) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(i));
});
```

help implementing this would be amazing, but some simple questions that could push me in the right direction is, is the merge of `pMergeSort` supposed to be a callback function? how do you define your call back function? Would it be better to use a pool of threads rather than trying to spawn threads? And the function wrapped in pMergeSort should be merge sort + splitting into threads right?

Comment: Threads documentation can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/threads